# Changing parameters within (multiple) Jlabels

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've a Swing GUI with 50 or so Jlabels:

```
{
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1, "0, 0");
    jLabel1.setText("AAPL 1453.54 2334.34 3234.32");
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0,249,0));
}
```

I want to be able to change the txt and colour without having to write a large bunch of conditional statements. What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking to write a method overWrite(String text, int hPos, int vPos){} to just add a new label in the place.

There might be a much better way to do this, I'm trying to make a crude stock display that changes stock prices and colour depending on an increase or decrease.

Comment: a JTable would be more suited for this IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, the solution below *is* ugly so I just came up with another solution... You can set a name of each of your labels so that you can get a specific label. And you do not need any **other** structure to hold the information.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setName("the_name");
```

You can then iterate (just like the other solution) over the components and get the specific one like this:

```
    for (Component c : frame.getContentPane().getComponents()) {
        if (c.getName().equals("the_name")) {
            // do the modifications...
        }
    }
```

---

Old solution: This is ugly but works.. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    frame.add(new JButton("Hello"));
    frame.add(new JLabel("World", JLabel.CENTER));
    frame.add(new JButton("Hello"));
    frame.add(new JLabel("World", JLabel.CENTER));

    for (Component c : frame.getContentPane().getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) c).setText("Friend");
            c.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Store your JLabels in a Map. Maybe key them on stock symbol, like this:

```
Map<String, JLabel> labelMap = new HashMap<String, JLabel>;
labelMap.put("AAPL", jLabel1);
```

When you need to update a label, look it up using it's key and change its colour:

```
JLabel label = labelMap.get("AAPL");
label.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

Also, think about using a JTable. Most stock tickers I have seen are implemented using one.